# Firefox initially unresponsive with Emscripten-compiled GLFW

Tags: c, opengl-es, glfw, emscripten

The C code below (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244133/how-do-i-get-egl-and-opengles-libraries-for-ubuntu-running-on-virtualbox/821812#821812)) uses OpenGL via GLFW to render a simple red triangle to the screen. I can compile it using Emscripten with the following command:

```
$ emcc triangle.c -s USE_GLFW=3 -o a.out.html
```

When I open the resulting `a.out.html` file in Firefox, I see the "powered by emscripten" and "Running..." messages that I recognise from the Emscripten repo tests; but my mouse/GUI/machine are now extremely slow to respond. Soon Firefox informs me that "A web page is slowing down your browser. What would you like to do?" I can choose "Stop It" or "Wait". If I choose "Stop It", the red triangle then appears, and all is well again. Can anyone tell me what is happening, and how I can avoid the problem?

I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 17.10, Firefox 58.0.1, and Emscripten 1.37.24.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_ES2
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static const GLuint WIDTH = 800;
static const GLuint HEIGHT = 600;
static const GLchar* vertex_shader_source =
    "#version 100\n"
    "attribute vec3 position;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";
static const GLchar* fragment_shader_source =
    "#version 100\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";
static const GLfloat vertices[] = {
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
};

GLint common_get_shader_program(const char *vertex_shader_source, const char *fragment_shader_source) {
    enum Consts {INFOLOG_LEN = 512};
    GLchar infoLog[INFOLOG_LEN];
    GLint fragment_shader;
    GLint shader_program;
    GLint success;
    GLint vertex_shader;

    /* Vertex shader */
    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertex_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
    glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader, INFOLOG_LEN, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n%s\n", infoLog);
    }

    /* Fragment shader */
    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragment_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
    glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader, INFOLOG_LEN, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n%s\n", infoLog);
    }

    /* Link shaders */
    shader_program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader_program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(shader_program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(shader_program);
    glGetProgramiv(shader_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader_program, INFOLOG_LEN, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n%s\n", infoLog);
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
    return shader_program;
}

int main(void) {
    GLuint shader_program, vbo;
    GLint pos;
    GLFWwindow* window;

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, __FILE__, NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    printf("GL_VERSION  : %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION) );
    printf("GL_RENDERER : %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER) );

    shader_program = common_get_shader_program(vertex_shader_source, fragment_shader_source);
    pos = glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "position");

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(pos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(shader_program);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Step one: turn on the compilers optimizer (`-O3` or `-O2`).

Comment: When you write "initially unresponsive" do you mean unresponsive until you kill the script or does it eventually run properly?

Comment: That looks more like C than C++ to me. I'd also suspect that the issue lies with the loop `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)`, AFAIK you have to control the (main) loop using `emscripten_set_main_loop`

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Step two: no change.

Comment: @nwp: As I say in the question: there is no red triangle, and my machine is terribly slow, until I click "Stop It". At this point I do see the red triangle.

Comment: @UnholySheep: Thanks. I'll look into that. Does that apply to all graphical programs, or just GLFW?

Comment: `emscripten_set_main_loop` is the key. I follow the pattern shown in https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/tests/test_glfw_get_key_stuck.c and it works. Thanks.